# Deploy AWS Elastic beanstalk to an environment in different region

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, aws-cli

I'm a little new to Elastic Beanstalk on AWS so forgive me if this is a little newbie....

But we've got an instance of our product in a new region (EU) and I'm unsure how to bind a specific git brand to deploy to that environment? (Using CLI3)

If it something best setup in the config.yml?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To do it once:
`eb deploy {environment-name} --region {region-name}`

To always deploy to it:

```
eb init --region {region-name}
eb use {environment-name}
```

Then use:

```
eb deploy
```

Comment: This works great, except when I deploy to the other region I get the following error ""ERROR: No Application Version named 'the_version_no' found ".  This only happens when I deploy to another region. if I deploy to another environment in the same application it works ok. Any idea?

Comment: Can you add a debug log, perhaps on pastebin? `eb deploy --debug`

Comment: @MrTomTom, it'd be nice to know how you solved, for reference :)

Comment: @LorenzoMarcon Oh sorry -- I am not sure what happened, but I recreated the environment and the eb deploy {environment-name} --region {region-name} mention above worked, not sure how what I did to the original application sorry!

Comment: It only seems to work if the application names are identical across regions.