# How to deploy AWS beanstalk instances in the U.S. region on AWS beanstalk instances in the Chinese region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Two services of a system exist in the AWS China region and the AWS US region.

According to this link：

[Deploy AWS Elastic beanstalk to an environment in different region](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29886795/deploy-aws-elastic-beanstalk-to-an-environment-in-different-region)

I tried to deploy an instance of AWS beanstalk in USA on an instance of AWS beanstalk in China.

I know the aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key of China is different from the aws_access_key_id and aws_secret_access_key of USA.

So I modify the two files : /root/.aws/config  and  /root/.aws/credentials

aws_access_key_id = (USA)

aws_secret_access_key = (USA)

Then I use this command:

[root@ip-10-0-0-111 .aws]# eb init --region us-west-1

**ERROR: InvalidParameterValueError - Platform 'arn:aws-cn:elasticbeanstalk:cn-north-1::platform/Tomcat 8 with Java 8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.7.7' is in a different region.**

How can I slove this question ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the error itself it's clearly showing that you are trying to deploy application using invalid platform value.By default `eb init` will take the current region platform unless you explicitly specify it. So it's using the China region platform to deploy in US region, this will fail.

If you compare the arns in the error and one which i below mentioned both have different substitutions. In AWS China region is in a different partition. For all other regions its `aws` and for China its `aws-cn`.

use something like this.

`eb init --region us-west-1 --platform "arn:aws:elasticbeanstalk:us-west-1::platform/Tomcat 8 with Java 8 running on 64bit Amazon Linux/2.7.7"`

For more details and eb parameter options refer the below documentation

- [eb init](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb3-init.html)
- [Amazon Resource Name Format for Elastic Beanstalk](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/AWSHowTo.iam.policies.arn.html)

Comment: Thanks very much! I will try it